# Excel VBA Find Loop to Verify Up-to-date Data Tab

Tags: vba, loops, excel, find

I have a list of ten measures in Settings!$AE:$AE (total number of measures can vary) and need to check with VBA if all of these measures exist in Data!$8:$8 (as column headers) using the name of the measure as the unique identifier.

The goal is for this macro to check if a measure exists in the Data tab, and to add a new column with the respective measure name in row eight if it does not. If the measure does not exist in Settings!$AE:$AE and does exist in Data!$8:$8, the respective column should be deleted. This will be used to maintain an up-to-date data sheet of measures (each row is lineitem by date by team member).

I can figure out the inserting/deleting columns, but what I need help with is writing a macro to check the Data tab against the Settings tab.

I searched around and it appears a .Find and .FindNext Loop is the solution, but I'm not sure how to write this as the What:= value, the measure name, changes at each iteration of the loop (Settings!$AE:$1, Settings!$AE:$2, ect.).

Would someone be able to provide a VBA code for what this should look like? Thanks! =)

Comment: You should loop through the source cells (in sheet Settings), and use `Find` within the loop. `FindNext` "Continues a search that was begun with the Find method. Finds the next cell that matches those same conditions..." ([FindNext Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195732%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps.

```
Sub myColumns()
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim wT As Worksheet
Dim rS As Range, rT As Range, Cel As Range
Dim l As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")
Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

'source range
With wS
    Set rS = .Range("AE1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE:AE").End(xlUp))
End With

'target range
With wT
    Set rT = .Range("A8", .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

'add source items to target sheet
For Each Cel In rS
    If IsError(Application.Match(Cel.Value, rT, 0)) Then 'doesn't exist in target, add
    'add to right of existing data
        wT.Cells(8, wT.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Value = Cel.Value
    End If
Next Cel

'clear target sheet of source non-matches
For l = rT.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
     If IsError(Application.Match(rT(l).Value, rS, 0)) Then 'doesn't exist in source, delete
        rT(l).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next l

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

DaveU, thanks for that. It pointed me in the right direction of using Match instead of Find. That solved my problem. Below is my code.

What it's doing, in a nutshell, is counting the number of measures in Settings! that match Data!, checking if that number matches the total number of measures in Data, and then doing the inverse. If both these conditions are true then the MeasuresInDataUpdated variable is set to true.

I ran through the logic on my white board and it seems to eliminate any false positives of the measures being updated. It feels overly through, but I think that's because the workbook is locked down and it would be difficult for the user to manually change something.

```
Private Function MeasuresInDataUpdated() As Boolean 'Check if the measures in Data match the measures in Settings

Dim MeasuresInSettings As Integer 'Set variable as integer
MeasuresInSettings = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Settings").Range("MeasuresNameArea")) 'Set variable to the number of measures in Settings
Dim MeasuresInData As Integer 'Set variable as integer
MeasuresInData = Sheets("Data").Range("MeasuresArea").Columns.Count 'Set variable to the number of measures in Data
Dim MeasuresThatMatchSettings As Integer 'Set variable as integer
MeasuresThatMatchSettings = 0 'Set variable to zero
Dim MeasuresThatMatchData As Integer 'Set variable as integer
MeasuresThatMatchData = 0 'Set variable to zero

Dim MeasuresNamesInSettings As Range 'Set variable as range
Set MeasuresNamesInSettings = Sheets("Settings").Range("MeasuresNames") 'Set variable
Dim MeasuresNamesInData As Range 'Set variable as range
Set MeasuresNamesInData = Sheets("Data").Range("MeasuresNames") 'Set variable
Dim MeasuresName As Range 'Set variable as range

For Each MeasuresName In MeasuresNamesInSettings 'For each measure in Settings
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(MeasuresName, MeasuresNamesInData, 0)) Then 'If measure in Settings is in Data then
        MeasuresThatMatchData = MeasuresThatMatchData + 1 'Set variable to equal itself plus one
    End If
Next MeasuresName

For Each MeasuresName In MeasuresNamesInData 'For each measure in Data
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(MeasuresName, MeasuresNamesInSettings, 0)) Then 'If measure in Data is in Settings then
        MeasuresThatMatchSettings = MeasuresThatMatchSettings + 1 'Set variable to equal itself plus one
    End If
Next MeasuresName

If MeasuresThatMatchData = MeasuresInData And MeasuresThatMatchSettings = MeasuresInSettings Then 'If the measures in Settings that match the measures in Data equal the number of measures in Data, and if the measures in Data that match the measures in Settings equal the number of measures in Settings then
    MeasuresInDataUpdated = True 'Measures in Data are updated
Else
    MeasuresInDataUpdated = False 'Measures in Data are not updated
End If

MsgBox "Measures In Data Updated: " & MeasuresInDataUpdated _
    & vbNewLine & "Measures In Settings: " & MeasuresInSettings _
    & vbNewLine & "Measures That Match Settings: " & MeasuresThatMatchSettings _
    & vbNewLine & "Measures In Data: " & MeasuresInData _
    & vbNewLine & "Measures That Match Data: " & MeasuresThatMatchData

End Function 'End function
```

Comment: Very neat coding!  The only suggestion I might make is to group all your Dim statements at the top of the module, and indent lines inside If,End,Else and For Next statements.  Makes for easier reading (and debugging).  Good job.